# How to Configure Masstransit Consummers by Autofac Modules

Tags: c#, module, configuration, autofac, masstransit

How to register Masstransit consumers in Autofac modules.

I have this code:

```
 builder.AddMassTransit(configurator =>
        {
            configurator.AddConsumers(ThisAssembly);
            //Bus
            configurator.AddBus(c => c.Resolve<IBusFactory>().CreateBus());
        });
```

And in another Module I have this code:

```
public class AutofacModule: Module
{
    public override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {    
        builder.RegisterConsumers(ThisAssembly);
    }
}
```

But the Consumers located in Modue assembly is not found by Masstransit.
Please help

**EDIT:**
I have multiple assemblies (modules) that are not directly referenced by the starting project. The assemblies are loaded at the application startup using MEF from a /Modules subfolder. The consumers are located in those modules. I use Autofac integration with MEF to load Autofac Modules into Autofac configuration.
When I say that Mass transit can't find consumers, I mean this:
when I put a breakpoint ate the line

> configurator.AddBus(...)

and inspect the configurator._consumerRegistrations field, there are none in it, only the ones from the starting application. Also when I publish events, none of the consumers located in those modules are consuming it. The events are only consumed in the starting application.

Comment: You don't need to register the consumers as in the second code snippet, the `.AddConsumers()` method registers them for you. It's unclear what you mean by 'the consumers are not found by MassTransit', can you give use the error you're getting? Also, don't use `_ => { }` if you plan on using the parameter, give the parameter a name. That may cause problems.

Comment: I have added more details and also renamed _. to configurator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the Autofac modules are loaded, and all of the consumers are registered in the container, you can use the following to register the consumers (and sagas).

```
    public static void AddConsumersFromContainer(this IRegistrationConfigurator configurator, IComponentContext context)
    {
        var consumerTypes = context.FindTypes(IsConsumerOrDefinition);
        configurator.AddConsumers(consumerTypes);
    }

    public static void AddSagasFromContainer(this IRegistrationConfigurator configurator, IComponentContext context)
    {
        var sagaTypes = context.FindTypes(IsSagaOrDefinition);
        configurator.AddSagas(sagaTypes);
    }

    static Type[] FindTypes(this IComponentContext context, Func<Type, bool> filter)
    {
        return context.ComponentRegistry.Registrations
            .SelectMany(r => r.Services.OfType<IServiceWithType>(), (r, s) => (r, s))
            .Where(rs => filter(rs.s.ServiceType))
            .Select(rs => rs.s.ServiceType)
            .ToArray();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns true if the type is a consumer, or a consumer definition
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="type"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static bool IsConsumerOrDefinition(Type type)
    {
        Type[] interfaces = type.GetTypeInfo().GetInterfaces();

        return interfaces.Any(t => t.HasInterface(typeof(IConsumer<>)) || t.HasInterface(typeof(IConsumerDefinition<>)));
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns true if the type is a saga, or a saga definition
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="type"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static bool IsSagaOrDefinition(Type type)
    {
        Type[] interfaces = type.GetTypeInfo().GetInterfaces();

        if (interfaces.Contains(typeof(ISaga)))
            return true;

        return interfaces.Any(t => t.HasInterface(typeof(InitiatedBy<>))
            || t.HasInterface(typeof(Orchestrates<>))
            || t.HasInterface(typeof(Observes<,>))
            || t.HasInterface(typeof(ISagaDefinition<>)));
    }
```

Comment: And I use it  in: builder.AddMassTransit(configurator =>
            {
                configurator.AddConsumersFromContainer();
                
                //Bus
                configurator.AddBus(c => c.Resolve<IBusFactory>().CreateBus());
            }); But from where do I get the ComponentContext?

Comment: It's the `c` in .AddBus() that you just quoted.